# run php in vbulletin 4 template

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am using vbulletin 4.1.7

I've read many tutorials out there but none explais properly from scratch how I should do, so im gonna ask here.

What i want to achive is in the header template i want to acced mysql database and echo some data. how would i achieve this

*this is header template looks like in admincp > style manager > common templates*

```
<div>{vb:raw mydatahere}</div>
```

Now how can I output my data in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a long time since I have worked with vBulletin, but I think what you need to do is make a plugin that is called by a hook that runs before the header is rendered, call mysql, and assign the result to a variable you then access from your template.

Since it is a template, you typically don't want to have database access there, as it is then no longer just a template, but has application code/logic.

Comment: @theswedishmoose: if you managed to get it to work then please post your solution. That is the whole point of SO and public forums. Thanks.